# align position of different symbols in legend R plots

Tags: r, legend

I have a plot using the map function in R.  I added a legend with a symbol, line and a box for three different variables, but the three symbols are not aligned.  The box is to the left of the other two symbols.  Does anyone know how I can get all three aligned.

```
   library(maps)
library(mapdata)

map("worldHires","USA",xlim=c(-75.5,-71),ylim=c( 36.5 ,42),col="gray90",fill=T)
box ()

legend(x="topleft", legend = c("2015 MAB Stations", "Scallop Access Areas", 
      "2015 Survey Domain with NMFS Strata"),cex=.7,bg="white",lwd=c(NA,NA,1),
      pch=c(4,NA,NA),col=c("black" ,NA,"black"),fill=c("white","gray99",NA),border=c(NA,"black",NA),
      x.intersp=0.8)
```

I have tried changing x.intersp, y.intersp, xjust, and adj with no luck.

Thanks